# ASP.NET MVC missing htmlhelpers

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I keep reading about html helpers for images and a lot of other useful controls. The problem is I only get a few in the intellisense. I only get about 18 and they all seem form orientated (radionbutton, dropdownlist, beginform, etc)

My web.config has the folowing:

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
  </namespaces>
```

That hasn't helped at all. I am using the default startup project for the RC build.

Comment: Is it just the Intellisense not showing the methods or you get runtime exception when using them? It has been long since I have quit relying on VS2008 Intellisense in aspx files.

Comment: I get runtime errors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471) project is what you need for the rest of the controls.

This contains the Microsoft.Web.Mvc namespace mentioned elsewhere. It's an experimental release, so isn't included with the main library or installer.

In the past, elements have moved from Microsoft.Web.Mvc to System.Web.Mvc as they mature.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these are in the experimental assembly, Microsoft.Web.Mvc.  Reference that in you project add it to namespaces in web.config.